# How to integrate live datastream in PyQt5 based QTreeView?

Tags: python, qt, while-loop, pyqt, pyqt5

**What am I trying to do:**

I am trying to make a live TreeWidget for monitoring my equipment's speed and ETA. I made a GUI in PyQt5 which is very basic(code is given below).

I want to get the live time(refreshing every second in the same cell) on the first column, in second column, I will be getting data from a websocket which refreshes the data every 1000ms for second and third column.

**What I did already:**

I put a while loop to iterate the data for first column (which is ridiculous). but once the while loop finishes, the last value is shown. which is perfectly fine. I want to use my GUI to connect with this kinda **while loop in parallel** manner. Thus it can grab the data in realtime. searched everywhere, but I only got a hint from a method called QDatastream in PyQt5, which i am not familiar with.

I want to know if it's possible to see the realtime data in the treewidget as i mentioned. If not, let me know if I should go explore QDatastream.

Thanks for reading my question. any help will be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import time

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(Form)
        self.treeWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 381, 281))
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName("treeWidget")
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, _translate("Form", "Time(s)"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(1, _translate("Form", "Speed"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(2, _translate("Form", "ETA"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.treeWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        x = 0
        while x < 10:
            self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", str(x)))
            x += 1
            time.sleep(1)
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(1, _translate("Form", "s1"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(2, _translate("Form", "eta1"))
        self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You will have to use multi-threading. There are [dozens of examples on SO](https://www.google.com/search?&q=pyqt+thread+site%3Astackoverflow.com) that can be easily adapted.

Comment: Thank you. after your comment, I tried the inbuilt threading method. which however led the GUI to freeze. Now I am exploring the QThread from PyQt5 which I think will help me out.